Proof of the Ľ Hôpital's rule
My math teacher was explaining the Ľ Hôpital's rule today and he added a dreadful disclaimer that not to ask the logic behind it. He added that his math teacher himself didn't know the proof of that rule. Initially the rule was fascinating but I wasn't able to come up with the logic. Then, it later struck my mind that
If the limit exists for a quotient of two functions at a point $a$ and is finite i.e.
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$$
Then as $x$ tends nearer and nearer to $a$, the numerator and denominator change but the overall ratio doesn't change i.e. because the limit is definite and is (to say) $l$.
Hence we may trace this process as
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x)+\Delta x\cdot f'(x)}{g(x)+\Delta x\cdot g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$$ (where $\Delta x$ also approaches zero).
As a direct consequence of the left-side equality, we get the Ľ Hôpital's rule,
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
Please give a comment on my proof and correct me if I'm wrong. If I'm right, then I'd be able to impress my classmates tomorrow. :)

Any decent calculus textbook will contain a correct statement and proof of l'Hôpital's Rule.  Or you can try Wikipedia. If your teacher doesn't know it, he should learn it. His teacher's ignorance is no excuse.

This is the right idea, but you had better write down carefully where you are using the fact that $f(x) \to 0$ and $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a$, since it's not true without that hypothesis.

You seem to have the logic backwards. Look carefully at the statement of L'Hôpital's rule.

You wrote hypothesis and conclusion the wrong way. You are pretending to prove that if $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$ (and $\lim_af=\lim_ag=0$), then $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$. This is false. $\frac{f'}{g'}$ may have no limit. Anyway, this is handwaving.

Okay, but one implies the other in this case, right?

The link between a function and its derivative is given by mean value theorem and in particular here we need to use Cauchy's mean value theorem. The main problem with l'Hospital's Rule however is not a lack of its proof, but rather the lack of awareness of conditions under which it applies.

The special case where $f(a) = g(a) = 0$ and $f'(a), g'(a)$ exist with $g'(a) \ne 0$ is simple to prove::$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a}} = \dfrac{\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}}{\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a}} =\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}$$ if $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous at $a$, then the RH side can be replaced with a limit, giving the form of l'Hôpital's Rule. The full rule is just a matter of loosening the conditions on this limited case as much as possible.

@PaulSinclair Thanks for the clarification. I misunderstood the hypothesis to be this special case. At least I hope my proof is correct for this special case provided that $l$ here is the indeterminate form (but, definite) for the first equation.

Less a clarification, but pointing out that this is the gist of why it ought to be true (at least for the $\frac 00$ case, but again for well-behaved functions the $\frac \infty\infty$ case follows from applying inversion and the chain rule). From there the rest is trying to see how much the "well-behaved functions" conditions can be loosened if one is more clever in the logic.
